# HTML external link working but image src not

Tags: html, asp.net

I am using external links for some images in my app. Links are ok, anchor tag works and it moves me to the exact raw image. The issue is that src of the image display broken image link icon;/

```
<img src="@img.Url" loading="lazy" style="max-width: 80%">      
<a href="@img.Url">Image Original Link</a>
```

Could someone help me?

Comment: Im using JSfiddle. Im also trying to add &amp; as a separator to the link but still without success. Any idea?
img link is:
https://carauction.axa.ch/javax.faces.resource/dynamiccontent.properties.html?ln=primefaces&v=8.0&pfdrid=733ef27dd30ff1909bf9faadd7fdc331&pfdrt=sc&place=articleGallery&fileId=276796&original=true&wmk=&pfdrid_c=true

Comment: Either the image is in a format that the browser cannot read or they are preventing hotlinking.

Comment: can I check somehow if they preventing hotlinking?

Comment: Well, if you download the image and put it in your site folder and it shows up in the browser, then they are preventing hotlinking.

Comment: you are right, after downloading image and put it to local folder - image load properly. But I dont want to downloads all the images. Instead I would like to show it in my app;/

Comment: Is there some way to bypass "preventing hotlinking" without download images to local?